# Only one variable is printing C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
//libraries
#include <iostream>

//standard namepace
using namespace std;


int Car() {
    int a;
    int b;
    
    cout << "Fuel Tank" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "MPG" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    return a, b;
}
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    
    a,b = Car();
    
    cout << "Print Values " << (a,b);    // <--- Line 25

    return 0;
}
```

Let's say you put 10 and 15 as the first and second input. Why is 15 the only variable to print in the `cout` statement on line 25.

Comment: The expression `return a, b;` will evaluate `a`, then evaluate `b` and return `b`.  Search the internet for "C++ comma operator`.  Functions can only return one value.

Comment: Similarly, `a, b = Car()` does not do what you think it does.  Functions return one value.

Comment: so there is no way for the function to return 2 values?

Comment: If you want to return and assign more than one value, place them into a `struct` or `class` and return and assign that.

Comment: Another alternative is to pass the two parameters, by reference.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Comment: kind of I am a little confused then what's the point in doing for example a = b, c; when you can just do a=b if that's what it means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how C++ works.

You need:

```
std:: pair<int, int>  Car() {
    ...
    return {a, b};
}
```

```
auto [a, b] = Car();
std::cout << a << ", " << b;
```

---

What you have:

```
int Car()
```

`Car` is a function which returns 1 `int`.

```
return a, b;
```

Here you have the comma operator which evaluates every argument and discards all but the last one. So it returns `b`.

```
a, b = Car();
(a, b)
```

Again the comma operator. `a` is discarded and `b` is assigned. Then `a` is discarded and `b` is printed.

Comment: the ```auto [a, b] = Car();``` doesn't seem to be working for me I am getting "language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'"

Comment: You need to set C++17 in settings > C++ > language or something like that.

Comment: thank you very much it was set to 14 is that bad?

Comment: I believe c++14 is the current default in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: No, it's not bad. C++ is constantly evolving. There's a new version every 3 years. C++14 must be the latest fully implemented version of your Visual Studio version so that's why it's the default. Every C++ version is backwards compatible (with very few and narrow cases).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Python, C++ does not have a built in notion of a tuple. Your `Car` function is declared to return a single integer, and so one integer you will get. An alternative is to use `std::pair<int, int>` in `#include <utility>` like so:

```
std::pair<int, int> Car() {
  // ...
  return std::make_pair(a, b);
}
```

I assume the program compiles because in C/C++, the comma separated expression list as you wrote is evaluated in order and only the last expression or item in that list is returned. So your first `Car()` function returns the last integer `b`, and you only initialize `b` in your assignment in `main()` to that other `b`. Likewise, your `cout` only prints `b`, hence 15.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend doing is making the function a void and passing the variables by reference. When you pass the variables by reference, you can change their value in the function and they will not be lost due to scope. This is because passing by reference references the location in memory where that variable is stored, instead of creating a copy like passing by value does (which you did).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void car(int &a, int &b); // function prototype calling for a and b to be passed by 
                          // reference

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    
    car(a, b);
    
    cout << "Print Values " << a << " " << b;

    return 0;
}

void car(int &a, int &b) 
{
    int temp = 0;
    cout << "Fuel Tank" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "MPG" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    
}
```

As you see, instead of returning values, the function changes the values of the variables by accessing their location.

Edit: Typically, functions will go below main and you have prototypes for the functions above main (as seen in my example).

Another thing, you named the function, "Car();". Typically, functions start with the first word as a lowercase letter with the following words capitalized. This makes it easier to not confuse them with constructor function names for classes, in which the first letter of the first word is usually capitalized.

Comment: Thanks! for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate it if you would rate my answer as "best answer" :)